# receiving email on a sunday morning

Tags: company-culture, work-life-balance, europe

What does it say about the culture of a company, when an executive assistant is sending emails on a sunday morning? We are in the same time zone and i sent the email on friday. I would not have expected and answer until say wednesday...

Comment: With only one data point, you can only guess about the executive assistant - and it would be just a guess at this stage.

Comment: It says the A.A. understands email is an asynchronous medium.  Maybe they're going to be out this week and is "cleaning up" old business before they leave?  Maybe they had an unplanned family emergency and are going to be working off-hours or remotely for a bit.

Comment: If you weren't expecting an answer until Wednesday, all you have to do is don't read the response until Wednesday. It is not clear why you see receiving a response earlier than expected as a problem.

Comment: I really don't understand all the downvotes. Nobody gave a reason for their opinion.

Comment: Read the answers/comments to understand the downvotes. What's your problem with *receiving E-Mails on sundays*? Why do you read your company E-Mails on sundays? (expecting you don't work on weekends)

Comment: Further, see: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/78916/in-a-company-crossing-multiple-timezones-is-it-rude-to-send-a-co-worker-a-work

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't say anything about the culture of the company. It says exactly what it looks like. Executive assistant replied on Sunday. Nothing more or nothing less. Do not over-read the situation.

Also, unless there is a reason you did not mention in the post, it does not make sense why you were not expecting a reply before Wednesday. Replying to emails is one the jobs EAs have. Whether they chose to reply on their holiday or during the workday is their business.

Answer (score 6):

It simply says that you check your mailbox on Sunday.

Executives in most of the companies are not bound to Monday-Friday 9-17 work schedule, so I think it is normal for them to send mail whenever they feel like doing it.

It's up to you to set the boundaries on how you deal with those mails. You don't mention the executive ever pointed out a delayed answer to weekend mail, so it's not a big deal.